# Payara server SSL error on admin-interface only

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, ssl-certificate, payara

I have a very annoying problem with a Payara server (4.1.2.181). I have a SLL cert (SAN) in a keystore with rootca, s1as, glassfish-instance.

On the http-listener the certificate is working fine, but not on the admin-listener. Never experienced this.

I have tested the keystore on another machine, then everything works fine.

I have tested with a different keystore containing a different SSL cert (but regular wildcard). Then everything works fine.

The log says:

> Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system,
>   Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, AcceptAll =
>   false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = true} due to
>   exception java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL
>   [rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root
>   exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection
>   establishment; nested exception is:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Anyone having ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Erik, have you found a solution to your problem, because it seems I have the same issue?

Comment: @Georgi No, solved it by using another SSL cert :(

Comment: Thanks @Erik. I did the same ... I guess this is the easiest way, if not the only one.